# React - Unwanted height change when rendering an input field

Tags: css, reactjs

In the snippet attached to this post, I'm trying to render an `input` tag when a user clicks on a `div`. The input has to take the place of the div, avoiding giving to the user any hint that the component is changed (like the `editablecell` attribute).

When the input is rendered, I encounter a change in the height of the eleme

```js
const styles = {
  cell: {
    width: "200px",
    border: "1px solid black",
    lineHeight: "30px",
    textAlign: "center",
    verticalAlign: "middle"
  },
  input: {
    width: "200px"
  }
};

const text = "Click on me";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        active: !prevState.active
      };
    });
  };

  handleKeyPress = evt => {
    if (evt.charCode === 13) {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          active: !prevState.active
        };
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.active) {
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            style={styles.cell}
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
            placeholder="Press ENTER when done"
          />
          <p>Notice how the height is changing</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div style={styles.cell} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            {text}
          </div>
          <p>Notice how the height is changing</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing `div` and `input` with each other, and `input` have an additional `padding` so that in increase the `height` by 1px. Add `padding: 1px` to `styles.cell` should fix.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with padding. Set it with a value and it will work as expected, take a look to this code.

```js
const styles = {
  cell: {
    width: "200px",
    border: "1px solid black",
    lineHeight: "30px",
    textAlign: "center",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    padding: "0"
  },
  input: {
    width: "200px"
  }
};

const text = "Click on me";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        active: !prevState.active
      };
    });
  };

  handleKeyPress = evt => {
    if (evt.charCode === 13) {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          active: !prevState.active
        };
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.active) {
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            style={styles.cell}
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
            placeholder="Press ENTER when done"
          />
          <p>Notice how the height is changing</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div style={styles.cell} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            {text}
          </div>
          <p>Notice how the height is not changing</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```